# how to free memory assigned using malloc?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, malloc

```
 struct element {
   unsigned long int  ip;
   int type;
   int rtt;
   struct element * next;
   struct element * edge;
};
```

I have a linked list. I create new nodes using malloc.
I tried to free up memory using free (ptr to node)
but when I run the traverse function again, I can traverse the linked list and the rtt value is correct as well as the next and edge pointers as I can follow the linked list. ONly the ip value is corrupted. why is this?

Comment: What did you expect to happen and why?

Comment: If you post a small piece of code that demonstrates the problem, I'm sure you will get some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory is not wiped when you free it - that would be a waste of processor time. It is just allocated to the "free list". That is why your data is still there

Whenever you free a block, you should set the corresponding pointer to NULL, so you don't accidentally reference it - it could be reused at any time.

Answer (score 7):

The behaviour of `malloc()` and `free()` depends heavily on the operating system and C library that you are using. In most implementations there are actually two memory allocators in play:

- The OS memory allocator, which uses the virtual memory facilities of the processor to provide a process with its own address space and maps physical memory pages into that address space for use.
- The C library memory allocator, which is in fact part of the application code and uses the pages provided by the OS to provide fine-grained memory management facilities, as provided by `malloc()` and `free()`.

In general, calling `free()` does one or more of the following:

- It marks the pointed-to memory area as free in the C memory allocator. This allows that memory to be reused. `free()` does not zero-out freed memory.
- It *may* return memory to the OS, depending on the settings of the C memory allocator and whether it is actually possible to free that part of the heap. If memory is not returned to the OS, it can be reused by future `malloc()` calls by the same application.

If you try to access memory that has been freed, usually one of three things will happen:

- The memory has been returned to the OS, and your program, typically, crashes. If you ask me, that is probably the best scenario - you have a problem, sure, but *you know it*.
- The memory has not been reused, therefore your old data is still there. Your program goes on as if nothing was wrong. This is in my opinion the worst case scenario. Your code appears to work correctly and, if Murphy has a say in this, it will continue to do so until it reaches your end users - *then* it will fail spectacularly.
- The memory has been reused by your program, and your code will start messing around with its own data. If you are careful (and lucky?), you will probably notice that the results are off. If not, well...

If you are on Linux/Unix [Valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org/) is a good tool to catch memory management problems like this. There are also replacement libraries for the C memory allocator, such as [DUMA](http://duma.sourceforge.net/) that will also allow you to detect such issues.

Answer (score 1):

Actually free doesn't delete anything, it just tells the OS it can use that memory again, for example next time you call malloc() it *could* overwrite some of your nodes.

Comment: I am not sure the memory is reclaimed by the OS. more like it stays on the program.

Answer (score 1):

Freeing the memory releases it for reuse. It doesn't necessarily destroy the data that was at that location. It is up to you not to access a memory region that has been released because the behavior is undefined (i.e. usually very bad).

If you want the data destroyed for some strange reason, then overwrite the memory area prior to freeing it (e.g. `memset(buf, 0, len)`).